# Populate text box value with number but not text

Tags: javascript, php, csv

So I have the following javascript function:

```
function updateValue()

{

var textBox = document.getElementById("projectName");

textBox.value = 

//(open php tag)

 $fp = fopen('data.csv', 'r');

 $data = array();

 while($row = fgetcsv($fp))

 $data[] = $row;

 echo $data[1][3];

 //echo "55";

 (close php tag)

}
```

Then I have my text field in my html code

```
<input type="text" name="orderedBy" id="orderedBy" oninput="updateValue()" />
```

I am am trying to pass a variable to the value of the textbox which is obtained from the csv file data.csv. The code works fine if the value in the csv file is a number but does not work if it is alphanumeric. If I comment out the "echo $data[1][3] and uncomment the echo "55" line the code works. Also if I replace 55 with something alphanumeric the code does not work.

Why are letters crashing this code.
Please help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just miss quotes arround value.

It should be:

```
var textBox = document.getElementById("projectName");

textBox.value = "

//(open php tag)

$fp = fopen('data.csv', 'r');

$data = array();

while($row = fgetcsv($fp))

$data[] = $row;

echo $data[1][3];

//echo "55";

(close php tag)
";
```

Comment: God I hate programming sometimes. Thanks very much